# PHP API to get Documents

Tags: php, api, elasticsearch

I am using a PHP API to post documents into elastic but I need to retrieve the last document posted according to it's timestamp.

The sense query I am currently using is this:

```
GET index-*/type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "size": 1,
  "sort": [
    {
      "timestamp": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have translated it to my PHP api

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'index-*',
    'type' => 'type',
    'custom' => [
        'query'=> [
            'match_all'=> []
        ],
        'size'=> 1,
        'sort'=> [
           [
            'timestamp'=> [
            'order'=> 'desc'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
$response = $client->get($params);
```

But it unfortunately keeps throwing errors and asking for 'id' but my ids are eleastic generated. I cant do it any other way. Is there a way around thsi? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [`search` method](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php#search-for-a-document):

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'index-*',
    'type' => 'type',
    'body' => [
        'query'=> [
            'match_all'=> []
        ],
        'size'=> 1,
        'sort'=> [
           [
            'timestamp'=> [
            'order'=> 'desc'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
$response = $client->search($params);
```

Comment: wow, thank you so much for a fast response. That was a stupid mistake on my part. Thanks,